# Example for adding attachment to email at mule

Tags: email, smtp, mule

I would like to ask how to add file as attachment in Mule (3.4.0)?

I tried many solutions and googled a lot but haven't found anything good.

This is what I have now (last try before posting here):

```
<sub-flow name="sendBackMail" doc:name="sendBackMail">
    <set-attachment attachmentName="changed.xml" value="#[payload]" contentType="text/xml" doc:name="Attachment"/>
    <logger message="Attachment ok" level="INFO" doc:name="Logger"/>
    <file:file-to-byte-array-transformer doc:name="File to Byte Array"/>
    <logger message="Attachment ok. Message: #[message]" level="INFO" doc:name="Logger"/>
    <smtps:outbound-endpoint host="${mailSMTP}" port="${mailSendPort}" 
        user="${mailUser}" password="${mailPass}" to="${receiver}" 
        from="${mailUser}" responseTimeout="60000"  doc:name="SMTP" 
        connector-ref="SMTP"  mimeType="text/xml" subject="msp2bass" >
    </smtps:outbound-endpoint>
</sub-flow>
```

It sends mail but I get content of xml file as body of mail.

What should I do/change so that mail would be sent as attachment. I get file from another sevice, do XSLT on it and then I should send it to some mail.

Any more info I should provide?

Thank you!

### EDIT

How I call bean:

```
<spring:bean id="SetAttachment" name="SetAttachment" class="si.irose.msp.cust.bass.SetAttachment">
</spring:bean>

<component doc:name="Java">
    <spring-object bean="SetAttachment"/>
</component>
```

Java class:

```
package si.irose.msp.cust.bass;

import org.mule.api.MuleEventContext;
import org.mule.api.MuleMessage;
import org.mule.api.lifecycle.Callable;

public class SetAttachment implements Callable{ 
    private MuleMessage mule;
    private String name;
    @Override
    public Object onCall(MuleEventContext eventContext) throws Exception {
        mule = eventContext.getMessage();
        String tryit="routeid";
        for (int i=0;i<mule.getInvocationPropertyNames().toArray().length;i++) {
            if (mule.getInvocationPropertyNames().toArray()[i].equals(tryit)) {
                name=mule.getInvocationProperty(mule.getInvocationPropertyNames().toArray()[i].toString()).toString();
                break;
            }
        }
        mule.addOutboundAttachment(name, mule.getInvocationProperty(name), "text/xml");
        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: Try the solution below discussion

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19523239/mule-smtp-send-email-with-attachment

Comment: I did but it didn't worked. At least with my settings not. What should I insert for value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok issue solved.

When you read from file inbound or generate with quartz (string or file) you can add "Attachment" directly BUT if you do an XSLT transformation and then try to send that payload via smtp, then you need to add "Object to String" transformer before attachment.

Final working solution:

```
<sub-flow name="sendBackMail" doc:name="sendBackMail">
    <object-to-string-transformer doc:name="Object to String"/>
    <set-attachment attachmentName="changed.xml" value="#[payload]" contentType="text/xml" doc:name="Attachment"/>
    <logger message="Attachment ok" level="INFO" doc:name="Logger"/>
    <file:file-to-byte-array-transformer doc:name="File to Byte Array"/>
    <logger message="Attachment ok. Message: #[message]" level="INFO" doc:name="Logger"/>
    <smtps:outbound-endpoint host="${mailSMTP}" port="${mailSendPort}" 
        user="${mailUser}" password="${mailPass}" to="${receiver}" 
        from="${mailUser}" responseTimeout="60000"  doc:name="SMTP" 
        connector-ref="SMTP"  mimeType="text/xml" subject="msp2bass" >
    </smtps:outbound-endpoint>
</sub-flow>
```

I haven't checked yet what transformer you need to apply if you do any other job instead of XSLT so if anyone wish to add some knowledge to this then please do so and add comment.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `set-payload` before the `smtps:outbound-endpoint` to set the body of the email to whatever you want, otherwise it will contain the same value attached with `set-attachment`.

Also remove the `file:file-to-byte-array-transformer`: it's unclear what it's there for.

Comment: That is reasonable, but I don't get attachment at all. Before body was xml content and now it is value I put into set payload. I think that problem is with setting attachment as I don't send any with mail.

Comment: This is strange but I've seen issues with the `set-attachment` configuration element. You can try by code using the `addOutboundAttachment` method on the `MuleMessage`.

Comment: Is there a way around for this or anything else to do about it? Maybe direction to useful links (but I did googled a lot before asking here)?

Comment: When you use `set-attachment`, do you get any error / warning in the logs? What about when you try attaching by code?

Comment: When I use set attachment there is nothing in log about this and also when I call java. Look at edit, I posted how I'm calling bean.

Comment: I don't get it, your code looks great. I'm surprised to see that in the code you use flowvars for attachments while the original `set-attachment` used the whole payload. Have you overriden the default transformers for the `smtps` transport?

Comment: Yes while I was trying to achive my goal I've put payload into variable. It's easy to change back and test it to set from payload as well but it gives me same result. How can I override default transformers? Or better, which transformer should I use? Code snippet would help ;)

Comment: I've checked the source code and by default Mule uses the right transformer (`ObjectToMimeMesssage`) so I was concerned about a potential change on the connector's default settings, but it seems it's not the case in your config. Truly puzzled :(

Comment: Welcome to the club :) I'll try to solve this during weekend but for not this should do the trick. If you come up to something (sooner or later) please tell me :)

Comment: Hey David, check my answer for solution. I had to leave this issue and try again later, now. This helps sometime if you stuck on problem. :) Thank you for your help in this.