# Sending a file attachement with Mule

Tags: mule

I have seen this answer but it does not show how you use the MEL to send the file in the value field. If you enter some value in there that is the content of the file. I assume you have to move the payload from the file endpoint connector to the attachment value property using MEL.

Also how can you set the content type dynamically

[Mule SMTP - send email with attachment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19523239/mule-smtp-send-email-with-attachment)

Thanks

Jaco.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `file-to-string-transformer` to transform your file to string. You can also use Mule variables, properties, etc for defining the content type or other params. Example:

```
<file:inbound-endpoint path="/tmp/attachments" responseTimeout="10000"/>
<file:file-to-byte-array-transformer/>
<set-variable variableName="ct" value="test/plain" />
<set-attachment attachmentName="#[message.outboundProperties.filename]" value="#[payload]" contentType="#[flowVars['ct']]"/>
<set-payload value="this is my message"/>
<smtp:outbound-endpoint...
```

Comment: Hi Anton. Thanks for this. All I want to do is send the file as an attachment. It should be the same type and content. It seems you are creating the file content. Lets say I have a folder c:\file and I copy a text file values.txt that contains the worlds hallo world into it. That file should be e-mailed as is. What I get now is that the content hello world is in the e-mail body. Lets say I copy a jpg file into the same folder. Then it should mail die jpg file and the e-mail client should be able to open the image. Does that make sense ?

Comment: Updated the example, it now works with all file types and includes original file name. For content type you will probably have to determine that by checking the file extension and set it conditionally for each type you want to support. Or find some library/script that does that.